# Postgresql initscript can't find pg_ctl after upgrading an ubuntu server to 15.04

Tags: ubuntu

I upgraded my Ubuntu server first from 14.04 to 14.10 and all went fine.

Then I upgraded it to 15.04 and on boot it now gives the error:

```
start-stop-daemon: unable to stat /usr/bin/pg_ctl (no such file or directory)
```

Searching for the file pg_ctl I have 2 of them

```
./usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl
./home/mick/TimeTrex/postgresql/bin/pg_ctl
```

So somewhere I have to change a path for the boot to use the correct one.

Timetrex is the only user currently of the postgresql database though I have plans to develop some other stuff.

Can someone explain what I need to modify for the boot to look in the correct place for `pg_ctl`?

Comment: More info.
I found that by running the command:
sudo pg_cluster 9.3 main start
I was able to start the datbase server and it works OK but this is a workaround and not a fix to my boot issue.

Comment: Typo Correction:
sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.3 main start